# Is there a word for someone who's skeptical only of statements that challenge their assumptions, and credulous of those that support them?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think of a skeptic as one who thinks critically of whatever statement they encounter (looking for alternate explanations, questioning sources, etc.)

Is there a different word for unevenly applied skepticism, e.g. if I am skeptical of things which challenge my worldview, and credulous of things which support it?

Comment: I think the term is "anti-scientist".

Comment: (Note that you are resistant to situations causing *cognitive dissonance*.)

Comment: Close enough to *confirmation bias* for me to call it that.  I'm not going delve any deeper.

Comment: @stevesliva As far as I can see, that is the most apt answer.

Comment: *closed-minded*

Comment: I believe you can consider bigoted. *Bigot* is a person who has strong, unreasonable beliefs and who does not like other people who have different beliefs or a different way of life.

Answer (score 3):

A **biased person** has a **lopsided view** of facts, and interprets them according to their interest.

> - [**biased**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bias) - "having a preference or an inclination, especially one that inhibits impartial judgment"; "a particular tendency, trend, inclination, feeling, or opinion, especially one that is preconceived or unreasoned"
> - [**lopsided**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lopsided) - "leaning to one side"

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't quite capture the whole sense of a "one-sided skeptic", but would cover many instances of a partial and preferential diluted sort of skepticism:

> **hypocrite**
>
> a person who acts in contradiction to his or her stated
> beliefs or feelings
>
> *the hypocrites who criticize other people for not voting but who don't always vote themselves*
>
> - [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypocrite)

Answer (score 1):

### Conformist:

> A person who conforms to accepted behavior or established practices.

Source: [Oxford Living Dictionaries (English)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/conformist).

Comment: Hi, Assen Robin, and welcome to English Language & Usage. This site emphasizes giving appropriate credit to outside sources of information (such as the definition that you cite in your answer). I have added a link to the probable source of that definition; please provide similar source credits in your future answers on this site. Thanks!

Comment: @SvenYargs Sorry for the inconvenience to you. And thanks for reminding me!

Comment: No problem. I'm upvoting your answer now because I think it's a valid suggestion (with a linked reference!), and I appreciate your taking my comment in the spirit intended.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite adjective to denote such attitudes is ***blinkered***.

ODO:

> **[blinkered](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blinkered)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Having or showing a narrow or limited outlook:
>   ‘a blinkered attitude’
>
> ‘I'm sorry that you feel I'm so clearly blinkered and entrenched and
>   incapable of having a reasoned discussion about it.’

Another word which works is ***prejudiced***.

ODO:

> **[prejudiced](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prejudiced)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Having or showing a dislike or distrust that is derived from
>   *prejudice*; bigoted:   ‘prejudiced views’
>
> ‘Of course, these beliefs do not reflect reality; they reflect the
>   prejudiced views of those who hold them.
>
> **[prejudice](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prejudice)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** Preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience
>
> ‘Some prejudices (preconceived opinions of an individual based on
>   opinions about the many) have names such as racism, sexism, or
>   ageism.’

Also, ***intransigent***.

ODO:

> **[intransigent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intransigent)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Unwilling or refusing to change one's views or to agree about
>   something:
>   ‘her father had tried persuasion, but she was
>   intransigent’